# The obtimum way to get the next and previous object of current obj in django

Tags: django-orm

There is a way to get the previous and next record using Django ORM.

```
next_obj= MyModel.objects.filter(id__gt=id).order_by('id').first()

previous_obj= MyModel.objects.filter(id__lt=id).order_by('id').last()
```

How this code reflected in SQL query, it's optimum or not? if not what's the optimize SQL query?

I think the optimize will start from given id then increased counter by one then search if the obj found return it else continue and increase counter while you didn't reached to end.